# Is BigQuery procedure execution completely synchronous?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking at the possibility of moving some of our simple model builds to use stored procedures. One of the sticking points for me is that it appears that procedures are entirely synchronous (even though they spawn child jobs, which would be done asynchronously). Is this accurate? There's no way to execute a SQL statement without waiting for its query job to complete?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts

Comment: I think that link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements within a multi-statement query do not execute concurrently, if that's what you're asking.  They execute sequentially, even without control flow.  That's true regardless of whether you include multiple statements, or you invoke a stored procedure with multiple statements.

You can issue multiple queries to run concurrently, but that's accomplished by creating multiple query requests/jobs, not via a single invocation with multiple statements within it.